# Adding Wiget Instance to Right Column from backend

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I'm new to Magento and working on customizing the Modern template, as its close to my ultimate design. However I noticed that for some reason the 3rd column in the 3 column template was commented out:

**/frontend/default/modern/template/page/3columns.phtml**
*[lines 43-55]*

```
<div class="main-container col2-left-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
            <?php /*<div class="col-wrapper">*/ ?>
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div class="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
            <?php /*<div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div>*/ ?>
        <?php /*</div>*/ ?>
    </div>
```

I copied this to my own theme, and modified it as such:

**/frontend/my_package/my_theme/template/page/3columns.phtml**

```
<div class="main-container col3-layout"> <-------
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
           <div class="col-wrapper"> <-------
                <div class="col-main">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_messages') ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('content') ?>
                </div>
                <div cla/ss="col-left sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('left') ?></div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-right sidebar"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('right') ?></div> <-------
       </div> <-------
    </div>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('footer') ?>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('before_body_end') ?>
</div>
```

In the backend, I created a static block with just plain text, and tried adding it to "All Pages", "Right Column"; but it does not show up. If I add it to "All Pages", "Left Column" it *does* show up.

I'm guessing that the Right Column reference somehow isn't in Magento correctly, but I don't know where to even begin looking to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a reference to right column in your `page.xml` (or your custom `local.xml`) for it to work.

Check this Classyllama article to see how to implement it in correct way:

http://www.classyllama.com/development/magento-development/the-better-way-to-modify-magento-layout

Comment: Useful, but doesn't really deal with my question. I realize that the proper way to deal with Magento in general is by using Local.xml, I still would need to directly edit the .phtml to add a column. But thats not my question, because the right column does show up correctly, but adding blocks from the Admin backend to the right column does not work.